# How can I extract standalone.tex from standalone.dtx?

Tags: packages, standalone, dtx, docstrip

`standalone`'s manual explains three ways of using the package.

1. `standalone.sty`: `\usepackage{standalone}`: for use with a non-standalone class, setting `\standalonefalse`;
2. `standalone.cls`: `\documentclass{standalone}`: for use standalone, setting `\standalonetrue`;
3. `standalone.tex`: `\input{standalone}`: for use with another class standalone, setting `\standalonetrue`.

However, TeX Live does not include `standalone.tex`. Thinking this was a packaging issue, I made a copy of the source directory, containing `standalone.dtx` and `standalone.ins`, and re-extracted the files.

```bash
cp -pr source/latex/standalone ~/
pushd ~/standalone
pdflatex standalone.ins
```

This produces `standalone.tex`, along with `standalone.cls`, `standalone.cfg`, `standalone.sty`. However, unlike the other files, `standalone.tex` is empty.

```bash
total 272K
drwxr-xr-x   2 <username> <username> 4.0K Gor   3 16:26 ./
drwx------ 103 <username> <username>  12K Gor   3 16:32 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username>  902 Gor   3 16:34 standalone.cfg
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username>  27K Gor   3 16:34 standalone.cls
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username> 178K Tach 25  2016 standalone.dtx
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username>  442 Tach 25  2016 standalone.ins
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username> 2.7K Gor   3 16:34 standalone.log
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username>  34K Gor   3 16:34 standalone.sty
-rw-r--r--   1 <username> <username>    0 Gor   3 16:34 standalone.tex
```

Presumably, this is why TeX Live doesn't include the file at all.

Now, `docstrip` is rather alien territory as far as I'm concerned. However, the `.dtx` certainly looks as if it includes code for `standalone.tex`:

```
% \iffalse
%<*standalone.tex>
% \fi
%
%\iffalse
%<*tex>
% \fi
% \subsection{Simple TeX File}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%%\ProvidesFile{standalone.tex}[2010/02/28 v0.4 Provides if-switch to show if file is compiled standalone]%
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \begin{macro}{\ifstandalone}
% Provides \cs{ifstandalone} switch which is |\iftrue| if the normal |\documentclass|
% was not yet executed (and subsequently redefined to be |\@twoclasseserror|).
%    \begin{macrocode}
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifstandalone\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\newif\csname ifstandalone\endcsname
\expandafter\ifx\csname @twoclasseserror\endcsname\documentclass
\else
  \standalonetrue
\fi
\fi
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \iffalse
%</tex>
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%</standalone.tex>
% \fi
%
```

How exactly am I meant to produce the `standalone.tex` file so that I can compile the following to typeset `abc` (in needlessly circuitous fashion)? (See page 18 of the manual.)

```
\input{standalone}
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\ifstandalone
  abc
\fi
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a standard `.ins` file and has

```
  \file{standalone.tex}{\from{standalone.dtx}{standalone.tex}}%
```

which I suspect was intended to be

```
  \file{standalone.tex}{\from{standalone.dtx}{standalone.tex,tex}}%
```

With that change

```
 tex standalone.ins
```

generates all the files including `standalone.tex` which then looks like

```
%%\ProvidesFile{standalone.tex}[2010/02/28 v0.4 Provides if-switch to show if file is compiled standalone]%
\expandafter\ifx\csname ifstandalone\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\newif\csname ifstandalone\endcsname
\expandafter\ifx\csname @twoclasseserror\endcsname\documentclass
\else
  \standalonetrue
\fi
\fi
```